# Recognize type of noise

Tags: visual-c++, opencv3.0, noise-reduction

What is kind of this noise?
Link :[Image](https://i.imgsafe.org/d0449d0.png)
How To remove it? I apply median and fastNlMeansDenoisingColored() functions but no improvement.

Sample programm:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


int main()
{

Mat img,gray,DENO, im_gray, img_bw, img_final;

img = imread("C:/Users/Opencv/Downloads/1.bmp",1);

cvtColor(img,im_gray,CV_RGB2GRAY);

adaptiveThreshold(im_gray, img_bw, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,      THRESH_BINARY_INV, 105, 1); 


dilate(img_bw, img_final, Mat(), Point(-1, -1), 2, 1, 1);

imshow("afa",img_final);
waitkay(0);
return 0;
}
```

Visual Studio 2012,C++, OpenCV 3.0.0
Regards

Comment: It is not noise.  More like dropouts, bad ones too since they last a long time.  Only shot you have is a median filter that only uses vertical pixels.

Answer (score 0):

I write these codes :

```
 ressu3 = zeros(m,n);
 for i=2:m-1
 for j=2:n-1
 ressu3(i,j)=1/55* median ([I(i-1,j-1),I(i-1,j+1),I(i-1,j),I(i+1,j-  1),I(i+1,j+1),I(i+1,j)]);
end
end
```

The codes is writen in matlab(for test).
Is it directional median filter?

Answer (score 0):

- Try below code for removing Noise,

  ```
  cv::Mat mainMat1 = cv::imread("input_image_path");
  cv::Mat dstMat1, medianMat1, finalDest1;
  bilateralFilter(mainMat1, dstMat1, 19, 19 * 2, 19 / 2);
  addWeighted(mainMat1, 0.40, dstMat1, 0.60, 0, finalDest1, -1);
  medianBlur(mainMat1, medianMat1, 17);

  cv::Mat dstination1;
  cv::fastNlMeansDenoisingColored(mainMat1,dstination1,10,10,7,21);
  ```
- Hope This will help.

Comment: Thanks. your code removed background Speckle noise, and the directional noise remaining. regards

Comment: @opencvtrain : if this code helps you then accept this answer.